# How to view/change the postgresql.conf parameter

Tags: google-cloud-sql

**In google cloud sql - Postgres .**

[1] How to view/change the postgresql.conf parameter like sharedbuffer etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limited set of parameters available via CloudSQL Flags: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags